# Does Apache.Ignite.Linq support async/await?

Tags: linq, ignite

The official documenation of version 2.3 https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/linq states this sample:

```
ICache<EmployeeKey, Employee> employeeCache = ignite.GetCache<EmployeeKey, Employee>(CacheName);

IQueryable<ICacheEntry<EmployeeKey, Employee>> queryable = cache.AsCacheQueryable();

Employee[] interns = queryable.Where(emp => emp.Value.IsIntern).ToArray();
```

I saw that ICache{TK, TV} has plenty of async support and am wondering whether it is possible to run Linq queries with async/await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/) does not have async methods for Linq.

Anyway, you can always use the construction like this:

```
var query = queryable.Where(emp => emp.Value.IsIntern);
var task = Task.Run(() => query.ToArray());
task.Wait();

var res = task.Result;
```

Comment: Too bad that id does not support it natively.