# Is there a specific reason why Ignite.NET does not support async queries?

Tags: ignite

Currently Ignite.NET supports async operations for a subset of operations on ICache .. however neither SQLQueries or LINQ queries support async evaluation.

This seems to be a glaring omissions since specifically on long running queries async support would help a lot with server scalability.... thus I am wondering if there is a very specific reason why this is not supported ...

(btw there also seems to be now way to go through all keys in a cache in an async fashion, which would also be helpful ) ...

Maybe someone can shed some light on this....

Btw, the suggestion here to solve this "issue"
[Does Apache.Ignite.Linq support async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100387/does-apache-ignite-linq-support-async-await)[Async/Await with Ignite Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100387/does-apache-ignite-linq-support-async-await)

is a really terrible idea for a server application where scalability is the focus and should never be implemented.

Comment: Have you raised an issue with the Ignite team?

Comment: Actually no, but i will certainly do so, ( and maybe if they want pitch in to implement this, as far as there is no convincing reason not to do so... ) 
However Stack Overflow Groups were recommended as a first point of contact from the Ignite team.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite.NET is based on Ignite (written in Java), and there is no async query API in Ignite, unfortunately. Since we just call Ignite API through JNI, there is nothing we can do to make true async API out of a sync call.

But, Ignite.NET Thin Client is in active development now, and it is Socket-based (no JNI), which allows us to make any async APIs we want. Async queries are in progress: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7154

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense now. I am guessing the new client will allow to connect ( through loopback ) to an embedded Ignite Instance within .NET Core still ?

Comment: Well, yes, you can connect to embedded instance with a Thin Client, but it does not make any sense, just a waste of resources.